# Passing 2 values to a js function from an HTML form using $_POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a form that I want to use to pass 2 values to a JS function using `$_POST`. I've tried doing just one at at time and it kind of worked, sometimes it would pass the value and sometimes it would be empty. I have two `select` in the form and I want to pass what is selected to the function. Here's what I've got:

```
<p>Add table to the Headings table</p>
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' onsubmit="return AddTableName('<?php $_POST['TableName']; ?>','<?php $_POST['YesNo']; ?>')">
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='AddTable'>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Table Name:</strong>
            <select name='TableName'><?php
                foreach($TableNames as $Table)
                {
                    //var_dump($Table);?>                            
                    <option value='<?php echo $Table; ?>'><?php echo $Table; ?></option><?php
                }?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Editable:</strong> 
            <select name='YesNo'>
                <option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p><input type='submit' name='submit' value='Add Table'></p>
</form>
```

and here's the function:

```
function AddTableName(Name, Edit)
{
    var y = confirm("Do you want to add this table: " + Name + "\nWith table Editable set to: " + Edit);
    return y;
}
```

I know that the values get passed to `$_POST` when I click yes in the `confirm` pop-up, but I don't know that it always gets passed to `$_POST` before being sent to the function

**EDIT**

I've tried removing the `onsubmit` from the form and instead using

```
$Name = $_POST['TableName'];
$Edit = $_POST['YesNo'];
$Results = AddTableName('$Name','$Edit');
```

This results in my page going blank. So I don't know what if anything is being returned. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: PHP runs on the server, JS runs on the client. It is impossible to directly call a function in one language from the other.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve with `POST` method? Why not pass the values and call function with button `onclick()`?

Comment: @AhmadM If I use `onClick` it would mean that if I click anywhere in the form, not just on the button and that is not good for what I'm doing.

Comment: @Mike You can use `onClick` only for the button, add this line of code: `onclick="submitForm();"` as an attribute to your button and define the function in `<script>` tag. You can also achieve this using jQuery with: `$('#submit').click(function(){ ... })`. (I assume your button's ID is submit).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can not working onSubmit, because PHP is a server side programming language (back-end) and he need to execute the code when he arrive to the action path ('Admin.php' in your case). Try to call this function on the Admin.php file when you get a POST request.

You can call this function with js variable in your case. So, you need to get the selected value of your `<select>` tags with js on button click, so you dont need a `<form>`.

```
<form action="Admin.php" enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST'>
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='AddTable'>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Table Name:</strong>
            <select id="tableName" name='TableName'><?php
                foreach($TableNames as $Table)
                {
                        //var_dump($Table);?>                            
                    <option value='<?php echo $Table; ?>'><?php echo $Table; ?></option><?php
                }?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Editable:</strong> 
            <select id="yesNo" name='YesNo'>
                <option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p><input type='submit' id="submitBtn" name='submit' value='Add Table'></p>
</form>


<script type="text/javascript">
    function post(path, params, method) {
    method = method || "post"; // Set method to post by default if not specified.

    // The rest of this code assumes you are not using a library.
    // It can be made less wordy if you use one.
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", method);
    form.setAttribute("action", path);

    for(var key in params) {
        if(params.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
            hiddenField.setAttribute("name", key);
            hiddenField.setAttribute("value", params[key]);

            form.appendChild(hiddenField);
        }
    }

    document.body.appendChild(form);
    form.submit();
}

document.getElementById("submitBtn").addEventListener("click", function(event){
            event.preventDefault(); // Use this if you dont want to POST it.
            var e1 = document.getElementById("tableName");
            var tableName = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
            var e2 = document.getElementById("yesNo");
            var yesNo = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
            if(AddTableName(tableName,yesNo)) { 
                post('/test.php', {TableName: tableName ,YesNo: yesNo});
            }
        });

function AddTableName(Name, Edit)
{
    var y = confirm("Do you want to add this table: " + Name + "\nWith table Editable set to: " + Edit);
    return y;
}

</script>
```

Comment: How would I do that without using a `form`?

Comment: Okay, that got the pop-up to work, but how do I now use the result either a `true` or a `false`? i don't know how to read what is returned.

Comment: What do you want to do now with your data, please be specific. Do you want to send a POST request on Admin.php ? And if you want it, please tell me with what data

Comment: I need to know if the user clicked `ok` or `cancel` in the `confirm` pop-up. Then if `ok` I'll be running a SQL script if `cancel` nothing. All of this is already on Admin.php That's the file that this code is in. It is currently looking for `$_REQUEST['action']` to be set then it switches on this based on the value (in the case of this `form` it's "AddTable"). When the case matches "AddTable" then it runs some SQL code to add data to a table.

Comment: just when you call your js function, call she like this: `if(AddTableName(tableName,yesNo)) {
       // now here you are if you clicked ok
      }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121967/discussion-between-stefan-burscher-and-mike).

Comment: How would I send this back into `$_POST` so that I can use it in the rest of my code? `if(AddTableName(tableName,yesNo)){ //send through $_POST['action']}`

Comment: I'll have to try that tomorrow, I'm leaving in just a sec. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Sorry for taking so long to get back to this, I didn't finish on Saturday like I thought I would. It does work in that it sends the 2 values to the `$_POST`, but when I click on `cancel` it still sends them and doesn't cancel.

Comment: I figured it out, check my post below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing in total to get it to work.

I used what @StefanBurscher gave me and then set the returned value to a Cookie that I can check later like this:

```
document.getElementById("Addsubmit").addEventListener("click", function (event)
{
    //event.preventDefault();  //use this if you don't want to POST it
    var e1 = document.getElementById("TableName");
    var tableName = e1.options[e1.selectedIndex].value;
    var e2 = document.getElementById("YesNo");
    var yesNo = e2.options[e2.selectedIndex].value;
    var TheResult = AddTableName(tableName, yesNo);
    //alert(TheResult);
    if (TheResult == true)// AddTableName(tableName, yesNo))
    {
        createCookie("AddHeadingCookie", TheResult, 1);
        //alert("This is what happens with a ok " + TheResult);
    }
    else
    {
        createCookie("AddHeadingCookie", TheResult, 1);
        //alert("This is what happens with a cancel " + TheResult);

    }
});
function createCookie(name, value, days)
{
    var expires;
    if (days)
    {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    } else
    {
        expires = "";
    }
    document.cookie = escape(name) + "=" + escape(value) + expires;
    //alert(document.cookie);
}
function AddTableName(Name, Edit)
{
    var y = confirm("Do you want to add this table: " + Name + "\nWith table Editable set to: " + Edit);
    return y;
}
```

Then here's the PHP/HTML that is creating the button and form:

```
<p>Add table to the Headings table</p>
<form action='Admin.php' enctype='multipart/form-data' method='POST' >
    <input type='hidden' name='action' value='AddTable'>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Table Name:</strong>
            <select id="TableName" name='TableName'><?php
                foreach($TableNames as $Table)
                {
                    //var_dump($Table);?>                            
                    <option value='<?php echo $Table; ?>'><?php echo $Table; ?></option><?php
                }?>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p>
        <label><strong>Editable:</strong> 
            <select id="YesNo" name='YesNo'>
                <option value='No' selected='selected'>No</option>
                <option value='Yes'>Yes</option>
            </select>
        </label>
    </p><p></p>
    <p><input type='submit' id="Addsubmit" name='submit' value='Add Table'></p>
</form>
```

And then here's the PHP that is checking for the `$_REQUEST` and the `$_COOKIE` that I've set:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['action']))
{
    //var_dump($_COOKIE); echo " Cookie<br>";
    if($_COOKIE['AddHeadingCookie'] == "true")
    {
        switch($_REQUEST['action'])
        {
            case 'AddTable':
```

This took much trial and error to get working and I couldn't have gotten it without the help of @StefanBurscher and the answer that he posted above. That's why his is marked as the answer and not this.